# Keep of level of nested keys for recursive dict function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I have a recursive function that grabs all keys from a python dictionary no matter what level of nesting.  While this works great, I am trying to keep track of the level of nesting for each key at the same time.  Some kind of counter, but not sure how to implement it.  Below is what I have so far:

```
d = {"12": "a", 
    "3": "b", 
    "8": {
        "12": "c", 
        "25": "d"
    }
}


keys_list = []

def iterate(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key not in keys_list:
            keys_list.append(key)
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            iterate(value)
            continue

iterate(d)
```

This returns:

```
keys_list = ['12', '3', '8', '25']
```

Right now the nested "12" is being ignored because it is already in the list, but I need some sort of unique identifier for the second 12 so it is included too.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `depth` argument to your recursive function:

```
d = {"12": "a",
    "3": "b",
    "8": {
        "12": "c",
        "25": "d"
    }
}


keys_list = []

def iterate(dictionary, depth=0):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key not in keys_list:
            keys_list.append((key, depth))
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            depth += 1
            iterate(value, depth)
            continue

iterate(d)

print(keys_list)
```

Output:

```
[('12', 0), ('3', 0), ('8', 0), ('12', 1), ('25', 1)]
```

This gives a list of tuples, where the first value in each tuple is the key, and the second value is the depth.

**EDIT**

the code below should cover different cases more reliably than the code above (but I did change your iterate function somewhat):

```
d = {"12": "a",
    "3": "b",
    "8": {
        "12": "c",
        "25": "d"
    },
    "test":"a"
}
KEYS = []
DEPTH = 0  # keep counter updated globally too
def iterate(dictionary):
    global DEPTH
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        KEYS.append((key, DEPTH))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            DEPTH += 1
            iterate(value)
    DEPTH = 0

iterate(d)
print(KEYS)
```

Output:

```
[('12', 0), ('3', 0), ('8', 0), ('12', 1), ('25', 1), ('test', 0)]
```

Comment: warning: this works for your example dict but i just tested with adding some more unnested dicts after the nested one and this gives the wrong answer, e.g. `d = {"12": "a",
    "3": "b",
    "8": {
        "12": "c",
        "25": "d"
    },
    "test":1,
}`, so be careful for this case! I'll have a look at improving the answer